# activating video calling screen when the app is not in background

Tags: flutter, whatsapp, videochat, videocall

I developed a video calling app using flutter which is working on both foreground and background. I want to active the incoming call screen no matter whether is in background or is being killed.

I want to make it just like whatsapp. Can anybody help me regarding the issue ?